# Api Management return empty response if origin header is present

Tags: azure-api-management

I am doing post request to API via Azure ApiManagement.

If Origin header is present and its not one of specified in Cors policy even postman will return empty response.

As soon as I disable Origin header I can get response.

So problem is following for web based application we must enable cors,

```
   <cors allow-credentials="true">
        <allowed-origins>
          ${env:CorsOrigin}
        </allowed-origins>
        <allowed-methods>
          <method>*</method>
        </allowed-methods>
        <allowed-headers>
          <header>*</header>
        </allowed-headers>
      </cors>
```

But our cordova app is also calling same api, and by default cordova will append `Origin: file://` Then Api management is doing strange things it will cut body. So response will be empty. If i do same request directly to azure function, I will get proper response back, and since cordova does not care (To a degree in our case is ok) about CORS I would expect api management not to cut response.

Also Api management will not allow me to enter *, because of allow-credentials="true" and also I can't set it to allow **file://**

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @VitaliyKurokhtin why Api management is doing what I am not asking :) See updated post

Answer (score 1):

APIM does not support origin with file scheme, only http and https. I'll see if we can fix it. But there the workaround for allow-origins=* and allow-credentials=true is to use expressions:

```
<allowed-origins>
    <origin>@(context.Request.Headers.GetValueOrDefault("Origin", "*"))</origin>
</allowed-origins>
```

This way response will contain sent Origin header value in Access-Control-Allow-Origin and not just * which is not allowed.

Comment: It look like a solution. I will try it

Comment: Would be nice to add to official documentation, so people dont waste much time on this :) Thank you

Comment: No its not :( if I provide origin: file:// I am getting {
    "statusCode": 500,
    "message": "Internal server error",
    "activityId": "6dd8a4ca-7a7e-477d-87bd-c3f7bc327b25"
}

Comment: Yes, file:// will not work either way. The solution above is for Origin: * and allow-credentials: true. Supporting "file://" will require code change, should come in a couple of weeks.

Comment: Is it possible somehow to get notification? Because right now we have huge problem with that... We now went to duplicate endpoints one for web, with predefined origins and app where we do allow all.